# How will I be able to process received CAN message in Python using can-isotp 2.0.3 module?

Tags: can-bus, python-can

I have a simple code as per below that configures the rxfn as well. However, the rxfn does not get called. It does not print on my console. Please help.

`Send` seems to be working fine since I am able to control my Controller with a known command. That is why it is commented out below.

```
from typing import Optional

import isotp
import keyboard
from loguru import logger
import can
import time


def cantp_error_handler(error):
    # Called from a different thread, needs to be thread safe
    logger.warning('IsoTp error happened : %s - %s' % (error.__class__.__name__, str(error)))


def cantp_txfn(isotp_msg: isotp.CanMessage):
    # all set_something functions and my_hardware_something are fictive.
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=isotp_msg.arbitration_id, data=isotp_msg.data, is_extended_id=False)
    logger.debug(f"Send: {message}")
    pcan_bus.send(message)


def cantp_rxfn(timeout: float) -> Optional[isotp.CanMessage]:
    # All my_hardware_something and get_something() function are fictive of course.
    msg = pcan_bus.recv(timeout)  # Blocking read are encouraged for better timing.
    if msg:
        print(f"Received CAN Message: {msg}")
        return isotp.CanMessage(arbitration_id=msg.arbitration_id, data=msg.data)
    else:
        return None


logger.info("Initialize CAN Interface")
config = {
    'interface': 'pcan',
    'channel': 'PCAN_USBBUS1',
    'bitrate': 1_000_000,
    'f_clock': 20_000_000,
    'data_bitrate': None,
    'fd': False,
}
try:
    pcan_bus = can.ThreadSafeBus(**config)  # Use thread safe version (blocks during Rx and Tx)
except Exception as can_thread_error:
    logger.error(f"Could not connect to CAN Bus: {can_thread_error}")
else:
    logger.info("CAN connection successful.")

addr = isotp.Address(isotp.AddressingMode.Normal_29bits, rxid=0x301, txid=0x300)
can_tp_params = {
    'stmin': 0xF8,  # 800us between consecutive frames
    'blocking_send': True,
}
stack = isotp.CanStack(pcan_bus,
                       rxfn=cantp_rxfn,
                       txfn=cantp_txfn,
                       address=addr,
                       error_handler=cantp_error_handler,
                       params=can_tp_params)

try:
    stack.start()
    print("Press 's' to stop the loop.")

    # stack.send([0x51, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0x05],
    #            send_timeout=2)  # Non-blocking send, does not raise exception.

    while True:
        # Check if the 's' key is pressed
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            print("Stopping the loop.")
            break

        # Your main loop logic goes here
        if stack.available():
            print("CAN stack received a message.")
            stack.recv()

    logger.info("Payload transmission done.")  # May have failed, use the error_handler to know
finally:
    stack.stop()
    pcan_bus.shutdown()
```

I've tried looking at the documentation https://can-isotp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/isotp/implementation.html#transport-layer, but no luck. I also looked at the examples but no luck receiving... or at least printing from the callback. I am able to receive with the `.available()` function from the transport library.

P.S. The results...
[results of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6reG5.png)